# Underline and Bold html broken in Android Lollipop

Tags: android, html

```
textview.setText(Html.fromHtml("<p><u>Hide post</u></p>"));
```

This code works properly on android 4.4 and below it is broken on Android Lollipop 5.0

Can anyone explain why some html tags are broken? **underline**, **bold**,  **subscript** ... etc

EDIT:

This is the full string which is failing in Lollipop

> Whatever may be its wider implications, the explosion of hydrogen bomb is, for the meteorologist, simply another atmospheric disturbance. It should therefore be classified with certain rare natural...**11**...***[A. programmes   B. occurrences   C. resources   D. laws]***, such as volcanic...**12**...***[A. insurrection   B. exhaustion   C. eruption   D. expulsion]***. But there are certain features of a man-made disturbance that requires special examination. As with all events on this...**13**...***[A. scanner   B. skate   C. snow   D. scale]***, it is impossible to describe what happens in details. However we can be reasonably sure of the main effects, and the most impressive of these arises from...**14**...***[A. pressure waves   B. pressure volume   C. pressure air   D. pressure gauge]***. The immediate result of the...**15**...***[A. reduction   B. commotion   C. detonation   D. distortion]*** is that the air surrounding the bomb is raised very rapidly to an enormously high...**16**...***[A. way   B. temperature   C. class   D. profile]***. The hot gasses expand violently as great...**17**...***[A. firearms   B. fireballs   C. fireworks   D. fire-smokes]***, compressing the air around them into what is called...**18**...***[A. shock-jocks   B. shock-therapy   C. shock-waves   D. shock-troops]***, or blast wave that is responsible for much of terrible destructive power of the weapon.
>      Another kind of wave arises because of the weight of the air. The force of the explosion lifts the...**19**...***[A. form    B.    atmosphere   C. space   D. height]*** around the bomb. The gravity waves can also resemble ordinary...**20**...***[A. stream   B. lake   C. ocean   D. river]*** waves. Waves of this type are normally felt by human beings and they have their effect on the weather.

Comment: Please explain what "broken" means.

Comment: It does not work, the text is shown as though the HMTL is not applied

Comment: It's working for me on Android 5.0 (tested on emulator), 5.1 (tested on emulator), and 6.0 (tested on Nexus 6). I pasted your code into a project I'm working on, and the text is showing up as underlined. Some things in Android 5.0+ automatically apply `android:textAllCaps="true"`, though, and that breaks applying a `Spanned` as you're doing via `Html.fromHtml()`.

Comment: I've updated the question with the exact HTML which is failing.....Any ideas anyone :(?